# How to mock new object without having NPE if the constructor creates new object inside

Tags: java, mockito

I have a test in which I do:

```
ByteReader csReader = spy(new ByteReader(any(), any(), any());
when(csvReader.readNext().thenThrow(new CustomException("")));
```

The ByteReader has the following constructor:

```
public ByteReader(InputStream reader, Charset encoding, Stopwatch sw) {
this.inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(reader, encoding);
...
}
```

The problem is - when I pass any() or any(InputStream.class) from the test, I'm getting NPE here: new InputStreamReader(reader, encoding); becase the 1st param there is @NotNull.

How can I workaround it so that I could catch it with Mockito and not to have the NPE?
I'm having some big troubles with it, so any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I would consider a 2n constructor taking InputStreamReader, mocking that reader instead of spying on object under test.

Comment: I wrote an answer for this, but I think you need to reconisder what you are doing.. Why can't the calling class be the one responsible for duplicating the InputStream Reader and then you just pass it into your constructor? The fact your tests are hard to write is indicating that the structure needs some improvement

Comment: HI @Toofy - you're telling the right thing. It's just I wouldn't like to change hundreds of lines of existing code.

Comment: can you add a setter for inputStreamReader ?

Comment: I see no need to change exising code - just use second constructor for test innwhich you need to mock the stream.   delegate existing constructor to the new one. For other tests consider in-memory streams like ByteArrayInputStream